# Vue assign style based on object value

Tags: vue.js

If I am rendering a list in template:

```
<div v-for"item in items">
{{item.name}}
</div>
```

and item.background corresponds to a color value, how do I set the background of div with a color of item.background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind inline styles with `v-bind:style` or use the `:style` shorthand.

```html
<div v-for"item in items" :style="{ backgroundColor: item.background }">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

You should read the [Class and Style Binding Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1).